# C++ check if pointer is valid?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having problems with valid pointers in C++. I'm using one object in different threads, so I can't just set the pointer to NULL and return. Here's what I'm trying:

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr = new char[1024]; //assume PTR = 0x12345678
    changePtr(ptr);  //after calling this,
                     //ptr is not NULL here.
    return 0;
}

void changePtr(char *ptr)
{
    delete [] ptr; //ptr = 0x12345678
    ptr = NULL; //ptr = NULL
}
```

How can I change `ptr` to NULL for both functions?

Comment: `operator new` is not available in C

Comment: The function can't change `ptr`. http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. Let's assume it's malloc or c++ :)

Comment: Note that there is no way to **check if pointer is valid** in the C++ language. The approach in the code is setting **a** pointer to NULL, but if there are more than one pointer referring to the same object, the rest of the pointers won't be updated. The test for NULL does not guarantee that a pointer is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, use reference parameter:

```
void changePtr(char *&ptr) {
    delete [] ptr; //ptr = 0x12345678 
    ptr = NULL; //ptr = NULL 
}
```

In C, you need to pass pointer to pointer, which is basically same thing with less pretty syntax.

You do not need to change the calling code. But you must give a modifiable variable as argument when calling, can't give for example `NULL` or `nullptr`, same as you can't do `&NULL`.

Comment: what does *& do? Never heard about it.

Comment: It passes reference to the argument caller gave. So when function modifies the parameter, it actually modifies callers variable directly. It is basically a pointer without using pointer syntax, basic C++.

Comment: @OvérFlôwz: `*&` is two separate tokens. `*` denotes a pointer (to `char`), and `&` denotes a reference (to `char*`).

Answer (score 7):

change the signature of changePtr to:

```
void changePtr(char **ptr)
{
   delete [] *ptr; //ptr = 0x12345678
   *ptr = NULL; //ptr = NULL
}
```

And call it using:

```
changePtr(&ptr);
```

Comment: I forgot dual pointers.. Thanks, it solved the rookie problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to manage memory in such a complex, error-prone way, then pass a reference to, rather than a copy of, the caller's pointer:

```
void changePtr(char *&ptr)
//                   ^
```

Much better would be to use a smart pointer; they are designed so that it's very difficult to leave them dangling when the target is deleted:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[1024]); //assume PTR = 0x12345678
    changePtr(ptr);  //after calling this,
                     //ptr is empty here.
    return 0;
}

void changePtr(std::unique_ptr<char[]> & ptr)
{
    ptr.reset();
}
```

although if I wanted a dynamic array, I'd avoid `new` altogether and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Personal rambling: this code demonstrates the basic problem of C++ IMO: when you do things properly, it looks just horrible. I mean, just compare the two definitons of that `changePtr` here... Requiring a complex syntax to do "the right thing" and providing a simple syntax to do "the wrong thing" is never good, no matter why it is so. +1 for this answer anyway, it's still correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a great many questions about how to check a pointer for validity.  A large number of these questions have been about Windows.  There may not be a general way to check in C++, but for a Windows specific solution the following seems to work on my system:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer;
    int cActualBytes;

    cActualBytes = VirtualQuery(&main, &lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer));        // Can we get info about main?

    if (!cActualBytes)
    {
        printf("Nope, you can't do that \n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (cActualBytes != sizeof(lpBuffer))
    {
        printf("Surprise!  Expected %d bytes, got %d\n", sizeof(lpBuffer), cActualBytes);
    }


    printf("Information for main\n");
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("C reports pointer %p, Virtual Alloc sees it as %p\n",&main,lpBuffer.BaseAddress);

    return 0;
}
```